# Change chart from cell ranges to named range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

is there a way to do vba by updating the chart data series from cells range to named range, because when i move and copy to a new sheet in the same workbook it changes back to cells range.

When i move and copy to another sheet it will change to cells range, what i need is a excel vba to replace the cells range to  named range. picture 1 is for sheet 2 and pictures 2 is for sheet 3

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdFok.png)

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f72Gb.png)

added new pictures below, as you can see, it automatically changes the sheet, which i move and copy to new sheet. i just want to change cell range to named range using vba automatically. [[image]
[[image]

[image]

what if i got more named range, how does this vba apply to filling up the same named range in each data range in chart.
[image]

Comment: I created a chart and applied a named range to the series, then copied to the same sheet and to a new sheet and the named range still remains in the series! What is your Excel version?

Comment: my excel ver is 2007 & 2010

Answer (score 0):

I started with Sheet1 and **created 4 named ranges** in the **context of sheet1** for series name, xValues, yValues and series plot order.

**After creating a copy of the sheet**, you can see in picture that Excel also copied the named ranges but now in the context of the new sheet name.

You have the procedure **test_updtChartSerie** that shows an example on how to replace the chart arguments (you don't need to use all) of the series order that you specify. **Set you named ranges here** and try.

It works for my needs! Enjoy and *don't forget to check it and vote if it was useful!*

[image]

```
Private Sub test_updtChartSerie()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim wsName As String: wsName = ws.Name
    Dim xtArgs(3) As Variant
    
    ' Example of updating series 1 with multiple named ranges
    Dim xtName$: xtName = "Chart_01"
    Dim sName As String: sName = wsName & "!" & "xt01_s01_name"
    Dim xVal As String: xVal = wsName & "!" & "xt01_axisH"
    Dim yVal As String: yVal = wsName & "!" & "xt01_s01"
    Dim sOrd As Byte: sOrd = 1
    
    ' Set chart arguments
    xtArgs(0) = sName
    xtArgs(1) = xVal
    xtArgs(2) = yVal
    xtArgs(3) = sOrd
    
    Call updtChartSerie(xtName, xtArgs)
End Sub

Private Sub updtChartSerie(xtName As String, xtArgs)
    ' SERIES(<series name>,<x values>,<y values>,<plot order>)
    
    Dim xt As ChartObject
    Dim xtSerie As Series
    Dim sOrder As Byte: sOrder = xtArgs(3)
    
    Dim sFmla As String         ' Series formula
    Dim sFmlaArgs As String     ' String with arguments
       
    ' Get and activate chart
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Set xt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_01"): xt.Activate
        
    With ActiveChart
        For Each xtSerie In .SeriesCollection
            If xtSerie.PlotOrder = sOrder Then
                ' ' Series formula: before change
                Debug.Print "before: " & .SeriesCollection(sOrder).Formula
                                
                ' Set series formula
                sFmlaArgs = Join(xtArgs, ",")
                sFmla = "=SERIES(" & sFmlaArgs & ")"
                .SeriesCollection(sOrder).Formula = sFmla
                
                ' ' Series formula: after change
                Debug.Print "after :" & .SeriesCollection(sOrder).Formula
                
                Exit For
            End If
        Next xtSerie
    End With
    
exitRoutine:
    Exit Sub
    
errHandler:
    Debug.Print Now() & "; " & Err.Number & "; " & Err.Description
    Resume exitRoutine
End Sub
```

Comment: Do I need to add Dim nr$: nr = "sheet1!xt_01"   ' Named range again, because I got alot of named range in the chart. Do I need to change sheet name in the vba or this vba can just replace just the Named range in the formula, because my sheet will be different when I move and copy just that my Named range change to cell range. Another question is what do set to keep the named range from changing to cell range.

Comment: As I told you, I created a chart and used named ranges on it and then copied the chart to the same sheet and to another sheet and the named ranges were not converted to changed to row and column references. For me , ``no VBA is needed``!  I uploaded a picture so you can understand better the code. It's just an example, run it step by step to see how it works and adapt to your code to suit your needs. The variable ``nr``, it's just to show that you can use a variable in the ``SERIES`` formula if you want

Comment: what i mean is, using sheet 1 to move and copy to a new sheet will reset my named range to cells range and the sheet =sheetname is change to a new sheet but the named range changes to cells range automatically. what im asking is if there possible to do in vba using current active sheet like =sheetname!named range, which sheet name will remind as the new sheet name and just change cells range to named range.

Comment: Can you post you a picture of your named manager that shows the names used in the chart?

Comment: added the pictures in my main post

Comment: When you copy an entire sheet, Excel copies also copies the named ranges with the same names to the new sheet. Because of that you have many named ranges with the same name assigned to different sheets, Excel does not know which one to use so it put cell references instead. You need to reassign the named ranges for the copied sheet to the chart. I believe that doing this in VBA is not that difficult. If you copy the sheets to keep the same structure, the size of data may vary upon each sheet and because you are using ranges instead of table objects, it is not dynamic.

Comment: Take a look a this [link](https://peltiertech.com/chart-series-formula/) by Jon Peltier. See it all, it explain the SERIES with and without VBA. You also have important links at the bottom of the page. Certainly you will find here the answers you need. I tell you it's not difficult!

Comment: im using offset formula and count as my named range, whatever i put in chart is base on the named range which count and automatically changes

Comment: I just replaced the post content. take a look.

Comment: updated regarding a question to your vba